# How to transform nested subfolders into a single subfolders

Tags: shell-script, find, bash-scripting, cpio

Whats a good way of “collapsing“ subfolders of a specified directory into a single folders whose name is a join the subfolders?

So given this directory structure…

```
./zero.csv
./reports/r1/a/b/c/one.csv
./reports/r2/a/two.csv
./reports/r3/x/y/z/three.csv
./reports/r4/x/y/four.csv
```

How could I specify subfolders of`./reports` should collapse - resulting in:

```
./zero.csv
./reports/r1.a.b.c/one.csv
./reports/r2.a/two.csv
./reports/r3.x.y.z/three.csv
./reports/r4.x.y/four.csv
```

Thanks

Comment: You wrote "collapsing *(certain)* subfolders". How do you specify or determine which folders to collapse? For example why not `./reports.r1.a.b.c/`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass-rename using `prename` aka `perl-rename`:

```
shopt -s globstar
prename -n 's{ (reports)/(.+)/ }{ "$1/" . $2=~s{/}{.}gr . "/" }xe' reports/**/*.csv
```

(Change `-n` to `-v` when the output looks right.)

Clean up leftover empty directories:

```
find reports -depth -type d -exec rmdir -v --ignore-fail-on-non-empty {} \;
```

---

prename applies Perl expressions (often `s/regex/replacement/` but not limited to) to each specified path. Here it uses `s{regex}{replacement}` to avoid slash-related headaches, matching paths against `(reports)/(.+)/`. With the `x` flag, the replacement itself is another Perl expression that keeps the 1st group `(reports)` but replaces slashes with periods in the 2nd group `(.+)`.